# Changing Python's Random Sampling Algorithm

Tags: python, random

Is it possible to configure internal sampling algorithm of the *random* module in Python to change default of *choice* and *randint* sampling from normal to some other distribution for the duration of the execution of the program (for example to tinker with *seed* or *state*), but to then just use *randint* and *choice* functions?

For example, I would like some left skewed sampling.

If so, would you please advise how.

Comment: Are you aware that the random module has other distributions - triangular, Gaussian, and so on? ( [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.gauss) ) Or do you want some way to do that without using those?

Comment: I am aware. I am just looking for the way to re-use API calls choice and choice by re-configuring the default normal sampling.

Comment: The default distribution is not _normal_ (Gaussian), but uniform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numpy library provides a [lot of different distributions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html), and the random library [provides a few too](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.gauss)

This [sample implementation of random](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27a4/Lib/random.py) suggests that exactly what you're asking cannot be done. Methods like `choice` call `random.random()`, by

```
def choice(self, seq):
        """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
        return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]
```

and `random` is only dependent on the seed. Manipulating the seed to change the distribution type would be quite convoluted, and surely violate the the randomness guarantees.

If you really wanted a module-wide change in default behaviour, you could modify `__builtin__` or hack into the module attributes, but it seems much more direct to

```
from numpy.random import beta
from random import gauss

def choice(seq):
        return seq[int(beta() * len(seq))]
```

or whenever needed, or put in a central location. I would also point you to a note in the random modules documentation

> Class Random can also be subclassed if you want to use a different
>   basic
>       generator of your own devising: in that case, override the following
>       methods:  random(), seed(), getstate(), and setstate().
>       Optionally, implement a getrandbits() method so that randrange()
>       can cover arbitrarily large ranges.

Introducing a `BetaRandom` class, e.g., would be trivial this way a much more maintainable, imo, than changing the reliable behaviour of the built in class (which may be possible through enough introspection and hacking)

---

I would also note that numpy's [setstate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.set_state.html#numpy.random.set_state) is **not** what you want

`*` stole a link from comment by  TessellatingHeckler

Comment: Thanks, en_Knight. How would I do randint with custom distribution in numpy?